# Implementing Find & FindNext functionality inside Windows form application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, presenter

I want to enable Ctrl+F or find or search functionality inside my windows form application.

My application comprises of a main presenter & sub-presenters.

My search is simple text search but inside different sub-presenters consisting of editable controls.

Whenever a search is found, focus is set to that sub-presenter's particular control.

But when Find button is clicked again, I want to start searching from last search result and not from beginning.

Is that possible to store presenter state? so that i can start from last search state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the previous line no in some global variable when u clik on find next start it form line no

```
static public bool FindNext(string searchString, bool caseSensitive,int line no)
            {    //Your code     }
```

Comment: My application consists of only Dialog's with controls & there string values.